# Rename interface from imported type

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script, I'm using the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar), which uses a default symbol  "Calendar", but I renamed it to "CalendarService". What do I need to do include this name change when using the [type definitions for Apps Script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script) in a TypeScript project?

Modifying the type definition file directly is something that I'd rather not do as it's an installed npm package.

```
// ./node_modules/@types/google-apps-script/apis/calendar_v3.d.ts
// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google-apps-script/apis/calendar_v3.d.ts

declare namespace GoogleAppsScript {
  namespace Calendar {}
  interface Calendar {}
}

declare var Calendar: GoogleAppsScript.Calendar;
```

As it stands, the naming creates two issues:

1. Usage of the advanced service isn't correctly picked up by the TypeScript compiler
2. I can't have a global `Calendar` (maybe an issue that can be treated separately, but I'd like to use that name)

```
class Calendar {
  id: string;
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  getEvent(eventId): GoogleAppsScript.Calendar.Schema.Event {
    // TypeScript cannot find `CalendarService`
    return CalendarService.Events.get(this.id, eventId);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify by including a usage example?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I added an example. I will check out aliases.

Comment: @TheMaster It's more of an issue with the return statement. I'll edit.

Comment: It seems [there is no easy way to do this other than  writing a extra *.d.ts file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15626)

Comment: @TheMaster Writing a new definition is something I tried and it works. There's still an unwanted global `Calendar`, which only exists in the dev environment. Not an ideal solution, but a valid one.

Comment: Then modifying the typescript definition should be the only way: `declare var CalendarService: GoogleAppsScript.Calendar;
` Then again, Not a expert on  ts. Maybe ts experts may have something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to commit changes to the type definition file, which allows:

- A full rename of the global `Calendar` variable to `CalendarService`.
- A visible and automated way for changes to be applied and shared in the project.

To setup:

1. `npm i patch-package --save-dev`
2. Add `"postinstall": "patch-package"` to package.json scripts
3. Rename declared variable in the type definition file:

   ```
   -declare var Calendar: GoogleAppsScript.Calendar;
   +declare var CalendarService: GoogleAppsScript.Calendar;
   ```
4. `npx patch-package @types/google-apps-script` (or use yarn)